# Google + cloud autobackup confusion

Tags: google-plus, picasa

I installed the Google+ application, I then enabled "Auto Backup" , and checked "Back up local folders"
it says "uploading 173 of 600" and some of the photos in the gallery have a "cloud" icon on them (I assume this means they are uploaded to my account).

When I go to my Google+ account I can't see any photo there. I even tried searching for #AutoBackup and there are no photos. This is an hour or so after I was connected to Wi-Fi, of course.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you are signed into the same account on the phone and on the PC?

Comment: And signed in on the PC at all, for that matter. Photos uploaded with G+ auto-backup are private by default.

Comment: I'm signed in at both places. When I upload a photo from the PC I can see it in the mobile app.

Comment: I even tried logging with the same account from a different device, and I see the photo uploaded from the PC there as well. But I cant see the backup photos in the second device either. What does the small icon of a cloud mean?

Comment: Is the could icon solid or just an outline? If it's solid the photos have been uploaded.

Comment: It can take some time for the photos to appear online. I think you just need to be patient.

Comment: The icon is an outline.  This means they are still uploading? @abraham

Comment: Yes. An outline means the photos are still uploading. You can actually watch the outline images fill up as an specific image gets uploaded.

Comment: I get it, not it works. I just had LOTS of photos and videos and it took time. Thanks a lot! I wish you make it an answer so I could accept it...